# How to read a library's versionName from build.gradle?

Tags: android

I want to log and report (in errors) what version of my library is being used. How is it possible to programmatically read `android.defaultConfig.versionName` from build.gradle *of my library*?

I have tried:

```
PackageInfo packageInfo = applicationContext.getPackageManager()
    .getPackageInfo("com.my.library",0);`
```

Where `com.my.library` is the package name of my library.

However, this results in a `NameNotFoundException`.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can access the version name of library projects using the library project's `BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME` constant.

For example, you can get the version name of the v7 support library via `android.support.v7.appcompat.BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME`.